# How to scrape the html data with same kind of tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How would I extract the Agency Fee, Bedrooms, And Bathroom's info using beautiful soup in python. [Here][1] is the webpage I am scraping.

```
<ul class="important-fields">
    <li class="">
        <span> Agency Fees: </span>
        <strong> AED 5000 </strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <span> Bedrooms: </span>
        <strong> Studio </strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <span> Bathrooms: </span>
        <strong> 1 </strong>
    </li>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am using beautiful soup and python

Comment: <ul class="important-fields">
<li class="">
<span> Agency Fees: </span>
<strong> AED 5000 </strong>
</li>
<li class="">
<span> Bedrooms: </span>
<strong> Studio </strong>
</li>
<li class="">
<span> Bathrooms: </span>
<strong> 1 </strong>
</li>
<li>
</ul>

Comment: Select or find_all? help please!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = '''
... <ul class="important-fields">
...     <li class="">
...         <span> Agency Fees: </span>
...         <strong> AED 5000 </strong>
...     </li>
...     <li class="">
...         <span> Bedrooms: </span>
...         <strong> Studio </strong>
...     </li>
...     <li class="">
...         <span> Bathrooms: </span>
...         <strong> 1 </strong>
...     </li>
... </ul>
... '''
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> spans = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.select('ul.important-fields li span')]
>>> strongs = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.select('ul.important-fields li strong')]

>>> spans
[u'Agency Fees:', u'Bedrooms:', u'Bathrooms:']
>>> strongs
[u'AED 5000', u'Studio', u'1']

>>> for name, value in zip(spans, strongs):
...     print('{} {}'.format(name, value))
... 
Agency Fees: AED 5000
Bedrooms: Studio
Bathrooms: 1
```

Comment: I did something same. The code is pasted below. Problem with this is that some fields doesnt have all the tags. e.g. in some tags Agency Fee is missing


imp_fields=soup.select(".important-fields li strong")

 for a in imp_fields:
   info.append(a.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
  j=0
  while j<len(info):
   if j==0 and info[j]!="":
    print "Agency Fee is: ",info[j]
   
   elif j==1 and info[j]!="":
    print "Number of Bedrooms: ",info[j]
   
   elif j==2 and info[j]!="":
    print "Number of Bathrooms: ",info[j]
   
   elif j==3 and info[j]!="":
    print "Size: ",info[j]

   j+=1

Comment: @AhmedMukhtar, Could you update your question with html that shows the fields without tags?

Comment: You are awesome. I modified a bit and it solves the problem well. Can I ask what does this line mean? print('{} {}'.format(name, value))

Comment: @AhmedMukhtar, See [`str.format` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format). It was used for string interpolation.

Comment: Can you help me in getting the same for the Property reference and other tags in the #listing-details-list li span. I am using for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li span"):
   print spans_others.append(a.text)

Comment: @AhmedMukhtar, I don't understand your comment. How about post a separated question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513445/how-to-get-similar-tags-in-beautiful-soup-python-web-scrapping

Comment: please check the post

Comment: @AhmedMukhtar, You'd better to be more clear about `all the above tags`. (By showing the expected output clearly).

Comment: As shown in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513445/how-to-get-similar-tags-in-beautiful-soup-python-web-scrapping
I want to get the following details

Property Reference:
Furnished:
Listed by:
Rent is paid
building 
Amenities

Comment: @AhmedMukhtar, I mean you should edit the new question with the expected result. (not commenting here the expected result).

Comment: thank you! I am sorry I am new here so aint familiar with the formatting etc

Comment: by the way its 0215 here too. are u in south Korea?kk

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to get the data from the HTML using lxml library in python and you can find examples in lxml tutorials (http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).

Comment: I am using python and beautiful soup

Comment: so what is the problem in what i said? lxml is library in python and you can use it easily

Comment: How about posting a code that help OP to solve the problem using `lxml` instead of only giving links to external resources?

Comment: external sources may have more information to learn from it which may not be applied in the example. but if i found that the resource is hard to read i can write an example.