# How to get similar tags in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div id="listing-details">
<div id="listing-details-list">
  <h3 class="listing-details-header">
  <ul class="important-fields">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span> Property Reference: </span>
      <strong> BLJLT/HSN/02022014/BNJM/DD </strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span> Furnished: </span>
      <strong> No </strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span> Listed By: </span>
      <strong> Agent </strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span> Rent Is Paid: </span>
      <strong> Yearly </strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span> Building: </span>
      <strong> Burj Al Nujoom </strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span> Amenities: </span>
      <strong> Central A/C & Heating , Balcony , Built in Wardrobes , Security , View of Landmark </strong>
    </li>
    <li id="details-agent-info">
      <span>Listed by:</span>
      <strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get all the above tags, using

```
for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li span"):
    print spans_others.append(a.text)
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what the problem is? I am using Beautiful Soup in Python.

Comment: As shown in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513445/how-to-get-similar-tags-in-beautiful-soup-python-web-scrapping
I want to get the following details

Property Reference:
Furnished:
Listed by:
Rent is paid
building 
Amenities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li span"):
```

There is no problem with this line, assuming you're trying to get all the `span` tags under the `listing-details-list` id.  See:

```
for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li span"):
    print a
<span> Property Reference: </span>
<span> Furnished: </span>
<span> Listed By: </span>
<span> Rent Is Paid: </span>
<span> Building: </span>
<span> Amenities: </span>
<span>Listed by:</span>
```

Your problem is that you are trying to `print` the results of an `append` call:

```
print spans_others.append(a.text)
```

and `list.append` always returns `None` (it mutates the list, it doesn't `return` anything).

```
a = [].append(4)

a is None
Out[19]: True
```

So either print `spans_others` after you're done appending to it, or `print(a)`, or etc.

Comment: I want to get the info of the following by using zip function of the spans and the strongs

Comment: I am printing spans_others but it gives none!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say with the first comment, and I can't reproduce what you're saying in the second one.  You'll need to be more clear.